# Finding set B when A and C is given along with relation .

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Set $C$ contains all the elements that can be represented using sum of an element of $A$ and an element of $B$.

In such a case if we have the values of set $A$ and set $C$, how can we find out the set $B$.

For eg :

If set $A=\{1,2\}$

and set $C=\{3,4,5\}$,

then set $B$ would be $B=\{2,3\}$.

I can work this around for small sets, but I fail to understand this for bigger sets, is there a global solution for this ?

Comment: Please, use "\{" to list elements of sets.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA no context  is correct .

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA : OP is trying to find $B$, not $C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you might have to go with a brute force solution.

You can easily find $\min(B)$ and $\max(B)$ by taking $\min(B)=\min(C)-\min(A)$ and $\max(B)=\max(C)-\max(A)$. After that I see no other way but looking at all $\min(B)<n<\max(B)$ to see whether $A+n\subset C$. If $A+n\subset C$ then $n\in B$, if $A+n\subsetneq C$ then $n\not\in B$. Note that this gives the biggest possible $B$.

There might be a more elegant solution out there, and there might be much better solutions out there for "nice" sets, until then I would just program a quick for loop.

Comment: what is A here in  A+n⊂C

Comment: So we have initial sets $A$ and $C$, and we try to find set $B$ such that $A+B=C$, so $A$ is already given. $A+n$ is just shorthand for $A+\{n\}$.